# How to insert a Pop up into a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on a Pop up but i'm unable to properly place it inside the container...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.show-popup').on('click', function() {
    $('.popup').fadeIn();
  });
  $('.close_pop').on('click', function() {
    $('.popup').fadeOut();
  });
});

var max = true;

function expand_collapse(elem) {
  var top_div = elem.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
  if (max === false) {
    elem.innerHTML = "&#9660;";
    top_div.classList.toggle("minimized", false);
    top_div.classList.toggle("maximized", true);
    max = true;
  } else if (top_div.classList.contains("maximized")) {
    elem.innerHTML = "&#9650;";
    top_div.classList.toggle("minimized", true);
    top_div.classList.toggle("maximized", false);
    max = false
  }
}

function close_pop(elem) {
  var top_div = elem.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
  top_div.style.display = 'none';
  if (top_div.classList.contains("maximized")) {
    max = false;
  }
};
```

```css
.container {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
.popup {
  display: none;
}
.pop_out {
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
}
.minimized {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.maximized {
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
.close_pop {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}
.close_pop:hover {
  color: red;
}
.expand_collapse {
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  height: 3px;
}
.expand_collapse:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}
a {
  position: fixed;
  top: 150;
}
```

```html
<html>
<link href="./index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<a class="show-popup" href="#">CLICK HERE</a>
<!--Right Here -->
<div class="popup" style="position:fixed;bottom:0px;">
  <div class="pop_out maximized">
    <div style="padding:2px;position:relative;"> <span style="margin-left:10px;">Tab 1</span>
      <span style="position:absolute;right:15px;">
     <span class="expand_collapse" onclick="expand_collapse(this);">&#9660;</span>
      <span class="close_pop">&times</span></span>
    </div>
    <div style="background:white;font-size:15px;padding:2px;">The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
      nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est
      laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  text
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./index.js"></script>

</html>
```

I'm trying to insert the pop up into the container whenever the minimize button is clicked. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any image or design showing where exactly you want the minimized popup to be placed.

Comment: @Samir Please click on the button above written Run Code Snippet, It Shows a Red Container where i want to place the Pop Up, you may also click the down facing triangle to minimize, Please vote my question :).

Comment: So the popup should be hidden behind the red background with only popup header visible including maximize and close icons?

Comment: I want it to be visible and above the red container, Try re-writing the code, i want the pop-up to minimize into the red container.

Answer (score 1):

Change `.popup` container from `position:fixed` to `position:absolute`

Add below css in `.minimized` class

```
.minimized {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

`bottom` property works when `position` is specified to the container.

`position:relative` will come handy in this scenario.

Comment: Hi samir, Postiton will not matter as the pop-up will be placed behind the container, and wont be visible there, instead i want a way where the pop-up will be placed inside.

Comment: z-index will give popup precedence over the red container. Add z-index to minimized class as specified in the post above. If still this is not what you are looking for please post a sample image of what exactly is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reduce the height (approzimately more then the red div).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.show-popup').on('click', function() {
    $('.popup').fadeIn();
  });
  $('.close_pop').on('click', function() {
    $('.popup').fadeOut();
  });
});

var max = true;

function expand_collapse(elem) {
  var top_div = elem.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
  var fatherDiv=elem.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
  if (max === false) {
    elem.innerHTML = "&#9660;";
    top_div.classList.toggle("minimized", false);
    top_div.classList.toggle("maximized", true);
    max = true;
    fatherDiv.style.zIndex="2";
  } else if (top_div.classList.contains("maximized")) {
    elem.innerHTML = "&#9650;";
    top_div.classList.toggle("minimized", true);
    top_div.classList.toggle("maximized", false);
    max = false;
    fatherDiv.style.zIndex="0";
  }
}

function close_pop(elem) {
  var top_div = elem.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
  top_div.style.display = 'none';
  if (top_div.classList.contains("maximized")) {
    max = false;
  }
};
```

```css
.container {
  height: 89px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
.popup {
  display: none;
}
.pop_out {
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
}
.minimized {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 89px;
  position: fixed;
}
.maximized {
  top: 89px;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 2;
}
.close_pop {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}
.close_pop:hover {
  color: red;
}
.expand_collapse {
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  height: 3px;
}
.expand_collapse:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}
a {
  position: fixed;
  top: 150;
}
```

```html
<html>
<link href="./index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<a class="show-popup" href="#">CLICK HERE</a>
<!--Right Here -->
<div class="popup" style="position:fixed;bottom:0px;z-index:2;">
  <div class="pop_out maximized">
    <div style="padding:2px;position:relative;"> <span style="margin-left:10px;">Tab 1</span>
      <span style="position:absolute;right:15px;">
     <span class="expand_collapse" onclick="expand_collapse(this);">&#9660;</span>
      <span class="close_pop">&times</span></span>
    </div>
    <div style="background:white;font-size:15px;padding:2px;">The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
      nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est
      laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./index.js"></script>

</html>
```

Log:
new var fatherDiv that is the container div "Popup";
add "fatherDiv.style.zIndex='2'" to set the Div in front of the red Div (z-index work like a layer,is like 2 layer of paper).
zIndex work only on the main container of a thing (in this case the Popup Div,may doesn't work on the children in some case);
add the "top" and "position" rule in .minimized because you can't use top without the position rule (i balance the position only to show you this result,you may balance this value in your file)
Say me what you think about this.

Comment: I would like for it to be inside the container not on top, Do you think you can try that?. Thanks.

Comment: Excuse me for absense i'll do it for you asap